# How to check if list contains dict element with same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I want to check if my list contains elements with the same two key values.
For example I want to aggregate through `category` and `weight` on the list below:

```
products = [
    {"id": 1, "category": "Furniture", "weight": 3.22},
    {"id": 2, "category": "Furniture", "weight": 4.55},
    {"id": 3, "category": "Furniture", "weight": 3.22},
    {"id": 4, "category": "Garden", "weight": 3.22},
]
```

Example above should return True

```
products = [
    {"id": 1, "category": "Furniture", "weight": 3.22},
    {"id": 2, "category": "Furniture", "weight": 4.55},
    {"id": 4, "category": "Garden", "weight": 3.22},
]
```

Example above should return False

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: how do you want to compare two dictionaries? by the keys 'category' and 'weight' and not 'id'?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`. You can group by category and weight, then see if any group contains more than one element.

Comment: @adirabargil yes

Comment: @chepner This requires first sorting by the desired key function, which is fine, but O(n log n).

Comment: @SvenMarnach True, but necessary in cases where the desired key isn't hashable. (Which is not the case here, so using a `Counter` to detect duplicates would be more efficient.)

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to first write a generic function to detect whether an iterable contains duplicates:

```
def has_duplicates(it):
    """Returns whether the iterable contains any duplicates.

    The items of the iterable need to be hashable."""
    seen = set()
    for x in it:
        if x in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(x)
    return False
```

To apply this function to your problem, you need to extract the keys you want to compare, e.g.

```
from operator import itemgetter
key_function = itemgetter("category", "weight")
print(has_duplicates(map(key_function, products)))
```

This prints `True` for your first example and `False` for the second.

Note that this will compare for exact identity, which for floating-point numbers in general is a bad idea.